# how to initialize a Variable tensor for the weight matrix in a keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, initialization, keras-layer

I am trying to use tensors variables to use as weights in a keras layer..

I know that I can use numpy arrays instead but the reason I want to feed tensors is that I want my weight matrices to be of the type SparseTensor.

This is a small example that I have coded so far:

```
def model_keras(seed, new_hidden_size_list=None):

    number_of_layers = 1
    hidden_size = 512
    hidden_size_list = [hidden_size] * number_of_layers
    input_size = 784
    output_size = 10

    if new_hidden_size_list is not None:
        hidden_size_list = new_hidden_size_list

    weight_input = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784, 512], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
    bias_input = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([512], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
    weight_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([512, 10], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))

    # This gives me an error when trying to use in kernel_initializer and       bias_initializer in the keras model
    weight_initializer_input = tf.initializers.variables([weight_input])
    bias_initializer_input = tf.initializers.variables([bias_input])
    weight_initializer_output = tf.initializers.variables([weight_output])

    # This works fine
    #weight_initializer_input = tf.initializers.lecun_uniform(seed=None)
    #bias_initializer_input = tf.initializers.lecun_uniform(seed=None)
    #weight_initializer_output = tf.initializers.lecun_uniform(seed=None)

    print(weight_initializer_input, bias_initializer_input, weight_initializer_output)

    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    for index in range(number_of_layers):
        if index == 0:
            # input layer
            model.add(keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_list[index], activation=nn.selu, use_bias=True,
                                       kernel_initializer=weight_initializer_input, 
                                    bias_initializer=bias_initializer_input,
                                    input_shape=(input_size,)))
        else:
             model.add(keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size_list[index], activation=nn.selu, use_bias=True,
                                    kernel_initializer=weight_initializer_hidden, 
                                    bias_initializer=bias_initializer_hidden))

# output layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(output_size, use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=weight_initializer_output))
    model.add(keras.layers.Activation(nn.softmax))

return model
```

I am using tensorflow 1.15.

Any idea how one can use custom (user defined) Tensor Variables as initializer instead of pre-set schemes (e.g. Glorot, Truncated Normal etc). Another approach that I could take is to explicitly define the computations instead of using the keras.Layer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works after enabling eager execution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

Add this at the top of you file.

See [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ISK4NqpnLvw_4ji8L4mMh-9xBKLGRQo6?usp=sharing) for working code.